# Creating a multiple field search function in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, autofilter

I need to build a linked search function in VBA that also auto-updates after you enter data into the given search fields. I have been able to do this successfully with the following sections of code:

Autofilter search - in a standard module

Code:

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
With Sheet3
    If Range("A3") <> vbNullString Then
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter
        .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("A3")
    Else
        Selection.AutoFilter
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Sheet change/auto-update - This is in a worksheet module

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        FilterTo1Criteria
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

However, within the sheet change page, I need cells A3:J3 to be the criteria, but I also need the auto search function to work if only A3 and D3 are filled in, or if just A3 is filled in (D3 is blank), or if just D3 is filled in (A3 is blank), but I'm having issues trying to compound the code to get this effect. How much more complicated will I have to make it? Are there some examples that someone is aware of that I can look at to glean some information from? It's hard to find any...

A slicer with a pivot table is a potential way to go, but I think some people downstream are using Excel 2003 and I don't think the slicer works back that far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the function to work if either A3 or D3 are not empty, then you can concatenate the two cells and compare that to vbNullString.

For the multiple filters, you can use a loop to set them all.

eg:

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet3
    If Range("A3") & Range("D3") <> vbNullString Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter
            For i = 1 To 10
                .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=Cells(3, i)
            Next i
        Else
            Selection.AutoFilter
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you wanted to set the filters as the criteria cells were filled, rather than all at once. Try this instead:

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet3
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter
        For i = 1 To 10
            If .Cells(3, i) <> vbNullString Then
                .Range("A6:J1015").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=.Cells(3, i)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

and for the new worksheet change sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$3:$J$3")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        FilterTo1Criteria
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This will add or remove filters as you add or remove criteria (row 3).

Comment: Thanks!  When I try that, it says I get a "run time error '424': Object required" and in debug mode it highlights the ".autofiltermode = False" line...

Comment: That hasn't changed from your original code... Has the nickname Sheet3 changed by any chance? What if you refer to the sheet by name instead...

Comment: Ah, yes.  I was using a slightly modified copy with only one sheet to experiment with new code.  That cleaned that up...but not, when I have data in a3 and d3 and run the macro, the screen flashes, brings up a little data for a bit, but then it returns nothing...

Comment: Are there definitely rows in the the data that match row 3 exactly? Because that is what the filters are now checking for, so will hide everything else. (That is what you meant by cells A3:J3 being the criteria yes?)

Comment: Ah, ok, I may not have been as clear as I probably should have been.  Ideally, each cell in A3:J3 will be some form of a search criteria.  I won't need all of them filled in order to return results...for example, if only the A cell is filled, which is a 'Type of Product', only that exact Type will be returned.  Then, if you go to G3 and put in what city, it will return the Type of Product in the respective city, with more and more search criteria in each cell.  Right now, does it require each of the cells to be filled out in order for it to return results?

Comment: Holy moly, that works like a charm.  May I ask where you learned all this??  I would like to be able to do some of this on my own...I've been learning python and I see a lot of similarity with the different If/Then statements, indentation, etc, so I think I'm on the right path.  Thank you so much though bobajob!

Comment: Glad it helped. As for how I learned this - a bit of logic and lots of googling! I'm sure you'll pick it up soon enough.

Comment: Haha, I guess.  I'm probably going to post a slightly related question to the solution you just provided, but it adds a bit of a twist into the search function I need, involving dates and trying to do all the above filter functions, but also throwing in pulling in products manufactured in between two dates.

Comment: Sure, though as always, have a stab at it yourself first. This site should really be a last resort after all your efforts (including much googling) have failed.

Comment: I agree.  I've searched for a ton of this stuff and I'm failing to link more complicated search functions together.  I've been able to do small individual searches in autofilter, but connecting them all together has been challenging. The date search function throws in a huge monkey wrench :-/